# Object from GIPHY API prints nothing

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript, giphy

I'm using angular 2 to get some data from GIPHY API.

```
export class ListaGifsComponent {
    gifs : Object[] = [];
    urlBase = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=";
    termoPesquisado = "ryan+gosling";
    key = "O8RhkTXfiSPmSCHosPAnhO70pdnHUiWn";
    constructor(http: Http){
        http
        .get(this.urlBase + this.termoPesquisado + 
            "&api_key=" + this.key + "&limit=10")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(gifs => 
            this.gifs = gifs['data'],
            erro => console.log(erro)
        );

    }
}
```

If I write console.log(this.gifs) , it logs nothing.

But if I write console.log(gifs) from inside the arrow function, it prints the object I want.

What do I do?

Comment: are you able to see the data after the service is called in console ? `console.log(this.gifs)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a race condition.  The arrow function inside `.subscribe()` is a callback function, meaning it is executed after the HTTP get returns.  However, this function is non-blocking, so the rest of your code continues to execute.  Thus, `this.gifs` may not be set when you try to `console.log` it.

To remedy this, you should use some reactive data type (like Promises or RxJS) so that you can get the value of `this.gifs` only after it has been set.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still having problems getting the url for the gif image. If anyone could help me, I'd appreciate it.

https://developers.giphy.com/docs/

Comment: @fabiomf can you be more specific about what is not working?